# Recaptcha Request timed out in bootstrap modal popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, recaptcha

I have 2 recaptcha in my site but in 2 different pages.  The first one does not have problem, the second one is situated into a modal popup, that is shown after  a button click.

The browser console shows this error:
[image]

and the captcha ends in an infinite loop:
[image]

Button that show popup:

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6" style="text-align:center">
    <button id="showModal" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-gray show_form" data-periodnumber="$idp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="margin-right:10px;"></span>__CONTATTI__</button>
</div>
```

My popup in this:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div id="request_titolo" class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Chiudi</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="request_titolo">__TITOLO_RICHIESTA__</h4>
    <small>__MESSAGGIO_RICHIESTA__</small>
    
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body frontend_request">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pan-info"></div>
    <div class="row">
     <form id="form_disponibilita" name="myForm" role="form">
      <input type="hidden" id="idp" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" id="langPW" name="lang" value="<?php echo $lang; ?>" />
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="prop_nome">__NOME__</label>
       <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>      
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prop_nome" placeholder="__NOME__" value="">
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="prop_email">__EMAIL__</label>
       <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>      
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="prop_email" placeholder="__EMAIL__">
       </div>
      </div>
        
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="prop_tel">__TELEFONO__</label>
       <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span></div>      
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prop_telefono" placeholder="__TELEFONO__">
       </div>
      </div>
 
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="prop_msg_ita">__NOTE__</label>
       <textarea id="prop_note" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>

      <!-- GOOGLE CAPTCHA -->
       <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
       <p style="color: black;"> Completa la verifica: </p>
       <div style="display: inline-block;" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf02WwUAAAAAHc2LtidX_HxU1C2iWn_e00-HAML" data-callback="callback"></div>
      </div> 
     
      <!-- END GOOGLE CAPTCHA -->

      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="prop_msg_eng">__PRIVACY__</label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="prop_privacy" placeholder="Accetto la privacy" value="yes">
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">__ANNULLA__</button>
       <button id="btnInvia" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-send" style="background-color: #cccccc !important;" disabled="true">__INVIA__</button>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>

</div><!-- Fine Modal -->
```

JS:

```js
function callback(){
    console.log("captcha ok");
 document.getElementById("btnInvia").style.background = '#1bb1d1';
 document.getElementById("btnInvia").disabled = false;
}

window.onload = function() {
    var recaptcha = document.forms["myForm"]["g-recaptcha-response"];
 recaptcha.required = true;
 recaptcha.oninvalid = function(e) {
     alert("CONVALIDARE IL CAPTCHA!");
 }
}
```

Can you help me?

SITE : http://www.residencecasacanazei.com/affittasi-vendesi 
For view the modal click on "Contatti" button

Comment: `CONVALIDARE IL CAPTCHA` What does it mean?

Comment: @ZainFarooq is a italian translate of "Validate the Captcha", the site is for italian clients

Comment: I have the same issue ;(. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
window.onload = function() {
    var recaptcha = document.forms["myForm"]["g-recaptcha-response"];
    recaptcha.required = true;
    recaptcha.oninvalid = function(e) {
        alert("CONVALIDARE IL CAPTCHA!");
    }
    recaptcha.reset();
}
```

Once you check the recaptcah it will automatically show timeout message after couple of moments. So I have put `recaptcha.reset();` at the end, it will reset it after submission

Comment: This does not work but creates other errors in the dev console

Comment: I have gone through your website. I don't know that why are you using javascript for this purpose

Comment: Use js for activate/deactivate the form send button (solution anti spam-bot)... in this page u can see the functionality http://www.residencecasacanazei.com/richiesta-informazioni

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with cookies. So I cleared the domain's cookies and after that the problem was fixed.